# Integrating Skype in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, skype

I have downloaded [Skype4COM](https://developer.skype.com/Download#head-7a2b6bffd67e4713f3bad371bf3ae9bf700e3527) from Skype

so my question is, can i integrate it with Asp.Net for creating Video Conference on the web ?

Comment: I'd suggest that you look through Skpe's documentation a little before throwing none specific questions like that out.

Comment: i have gone through it and i know it supports desktop application, but i am not sure about web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, no. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

I'll hazard a guess and suggest that the client side would have to available on the client desktop - and accessed on the page via active x or possibly javascript. This would mean a local installation on skype I'd reckon.